# Android SDK with Ubuntu 12.04 Panics

Tags: android, sdk, panic

I try to run the Android SDK on Ubuntu 12.04. I opened the Android SDK Manager and installed the 'Tools' and 'Android 4.1' but when going to `Tools->Manage AVDs` and creating a new AVD and starting it I get the error `PANIC: Could not open: /home/.../.android/avd/AVD.ini`.
The Android SDK is located in `/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`.
Why can't it find the `.ini` file??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might want to make android avd with sd card support. and thats why it is giving error because you are not giving any permission to your android sdk manager about this.

all you have to do is Run below Command:

open terminal-->log in as root

and type

chmod -R 777 'YOURPATH(Just Drag and Drop your Android sdk folder here)'

press enter.

thats all.

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: Ok I tried:
chmod -R 777 /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/
and then I created a new AVD with SD Card size 1024 MB but it did not work I still get the same error by starting the emulator with
sudo bash emulator @avd  //avd is the name of the AVD

Comment: Hello @Bhavesh, do you mean using 'sudo su' to log in as root? I did and still have no result.

Comment: @mihata: to Login as Root Do it By writing "su root" after opening your terminal--> Press Enter-->Write "root"(Password)--> Press Enter..you are now logged in as Root.